# Is there any convention for a helper class in Android?

Tags: android, helper, conventions

For every Activity I add to my app I'm noticing a lot of similar code being used in the initialization of the Activity. A helper class with a static method to wrap this similar code seems the way to go.

I first thought of a singleton class. I could add static methods/variables and use them across the application. I haven't really tried to see how would this work in an Android application. Searching a little bit more I saw something about creating a class extending `Application`. For this I did a simple test:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    public static String DEMOTEXT = "WORKING!";

    public static void ShowToast(Context context, String text) {
        Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

MyApp.ShowToast(this, MyApp.DEMOTEXT); // Placed on onCreate of some Activity
```

This works exactly as I expected. Is this the way to go on Android or is there a better convention? Anything else I should consider when doing this?

By the way, should I use the  `final` keyword on the string? What about the method?

**EDIT:** I just read this:

> There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation,
>   static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular
>   way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register
>   broadcast receivers), the function to retrieve it can be given a
>   Context which internally uses Context.getApplicationContext() when
>   first constructing the singleton.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Should I use a singleton then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) is primarily used for a global application initialization. You would create your own class, override [Application.onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate%28%29) and initialize your static application data there.

Dont forget to declare it in the AndroidMainfest.xml:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="your.package.path.to.MyApp">
```

A static helper class is made the way you did.
The convention is to use lower case letter at first position, so `MyApp.showToast(...)`.

You would use `final` for the String if you would want to avoid madifications on other places (since it should be a contant).

```
// this would allow ...
public static String DEMOTEXT = "WORKING!";

// ... to do this somewhere else
MyApp.DEMOTEXT = "NOT WORKING!"
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this but I think you should be able to do something like this as well.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String DEMOTEXT = "WORKING!";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) 
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        Toast.makeText(this, DEMOTEXT, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Now for all activities that need to use that initialization could just extend your base activity class.

```
public class SomeActivity extends MyActivity {
    ...
    // Should display the toast on create
    ...
}
```

Comment: My code was just an example. I can't do that because my actual methods will have arguments and will depend on the actual Activity, so I can't just create a base class like that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes just use a singleton.  Well in this case if your methods are static, you don't even need a singleton.  Just a class with static methods.

Comment: But the singleton would also prevent the class from being instantiated. In the case that's a required condition...